# How can I prevent Joomla from loading template.css when opening a page in a modal

Tags: plugin, bootstrap, modal

I am using the Membership Pro plugin on a page, and there is a link to a terms and conditions page that comes from the plugin. I am opening this link in a bootstrap modal which is working great. The problem I am having is that Joomla is loading template.css when this modal pops up, which is causing all my styles on the main page to be messed up.

Is there a way to prevent Joomla from loading this file on certain pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modals aree usually loaded using the URL parameter `template=component`. That means that instead of the regular `templates/your_template/index.php` Joomla will use `templates/your_template/component.php`.

This `component.php` file is supposed to only load the component output without any module positions. Joomla will also only load the CSS files defined there.

Comment: Okay so maybe I should go into the component.php file and make it so it does not load that css file on the pages i dont want it.

Comment: Yeah I just added an if statement to the component file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI, I know it won't help much since you're using bootstrap, but if you use JCE to create the popup and you choose Internal Link as the link type, it will do this for you. It has the added benefit of loading the CSS styles but not the page container, so your pop up text still looks good. If you end up editing component.php, you might want to add some inline styles there or load a css file if you find your popup isn't styled at all.